# Table Header with vertically centered alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, xetex, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I'm creating table header using LaTeX code mentioned below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\textbf{Q }$&$\textbf{Header one}$&$\textbf{Test} $&$\textbf{Test1}$&$\textbf{Test2}$&$\textbf{Test3}$\\
$ $&$ $&$\textbf{Text4} $&$\textbf{Text5}$&$\textbf{Text6}$&$\textbf{Text7}$\\
$ $&$ $&$ $&$$&$$&$\textbf{Text8}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}$
```

Can you please suggest, how can I arrange this vertically aligned centrally? 
[Note: I'm looking for option to centrally align text inside header, which is currently spread across three lines.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new verion, after clarification. No additional packages used. Each column is a separate table. `$`'s left, however rather unneeded.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

\def\barr{\begin{tabular}{l}}
\def\earr{\end{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\textbf{Q }$&
\barr 
$\textbf{Header one}$
\earr &
\barr
$\textbf{Test}$\\
$\textbf{Text4} $\\
\earr &
\barr
$\textbf{Test1}$\\
$\textbf{Text5}$
\earr &
\barr
$\textbf{Test2}$\\
$\textbf{Text6}$
\earr &
\barr
$\textbf{Test3}$\\
$\textbf{Text7}$\\
$\textbf{Text8}$
\earr\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good; I'm looking for option to centrally align "Text 1 Text5"

Comment: @PawanMude A new version added. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

Probably this is what you want:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{1.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|M|m{3cm}|M|M|M|M|}
\hline
\textbf{Q} &
\textbf{Header one} &
\textbf{Test \newline Text4} &
\textbf{Test1 \newline Text5} &
\textbf{Test2 \newline Text6} &
\textbf{Test3 \newline Text7 \newline Text8}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you want different widths for columns, you can declare the `\newcolumntype` to have an optional argument, like

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

Also, if you want all the table to be in boldface, you can add `\bfseries` in that declaration

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}\bfseries}m{#1}}
```

So, the previous code can be modified as

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}\bfseries}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}\bfseries}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|M{1cm}|N{3cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
\hline
Q &
Header one &
Test \newline Text4 &
Test1 \newline Text5 &
Test2 \newline Text6 &
Test3 \newline Text7 \newline Text8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: You could simplify expressions such as `\textbf{Test2}\newline\textbf{Text6}` to `\textbf{Test2 \newline Text6}`. :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller ; Thanks for providing solution and updated comment , this is something new I learnt

Comment: @Mico Yes, thanks, I was in a hurry... I've modified the code.

Comment: @PawanMude You're welcome. I've added some more information. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to create a column type that will wrap long lines while centering the contents of the column.

One method for doing this, which makes use of the `array` package (a package that's included in all LaTeX distributions I know of), creates a new column type called "C" to do the job. You should, of course, set the width of the column to suit your specific needs.

By the way, there's no need to encase material that's set using `\textbf` in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.25cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{Q} & 
\textbf{Header one} & 
\textbf{Test Text4} & 
\textbf{Test1 Text5} & 
\textbf{Test2 Text6} & 
\textbf{Test3 Text7 Text8}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You for providing comment on above post "\textbf{Test2 \newline Text6}"